# On groups of four elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

> > Prove that there is no group consists of 4 elements $a ,b ,c, d$ such that $a^2=c, bc=d$.

This is what I understand. For a set $G$ to be a Group with respect to some binary operation $*$, four conditions must hold:

1. $G$ is closed under $*$
2. $*$ is associative for all elements in $G$.
3. G has an identity element $e$
4. $G$ contains inverses for each element in $G$.

My idea was to show that one of the four conditions above does not hold, thus not being a group. It would be difficult to prove whether or not it is closed with the given information. Multiplication is associative so that's out of the picture too. Thus, these ideas are out. I think showing this set does not have an identity would be suffice. My question is, how would I actually showcase that. Would creating a multiplication table by the Sudoku method?

---

I want to thank you for taking the time to read this question. I greatly appreciate any assistance you provide.

Comment: Note that if there exists such a group, then one of $a,b,c,d$ must be the identity element, you might deduce a contradiction from this

Comment: Which element is the identity? Keep in mind that no two of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are equal. Once you know which it is, think about the pairs of inverses.

Comment: Any [group of order 4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208740/cayley-tables-for-two-non-isomorphic-groups-of-order-4) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_4}$ or $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}.$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**.  If $a$ is the identity then so is $a^2$, therefore so is $c$, which is impossible if $a$ and $c$ are supposed to be different.

You can show in the same way that neither $b$ nor $c$ is the identity.

It is a little harder to deal with $d$, but if $d$ is the identity, then what are the inverses of $b$ and $c$?  What is the inverse of $a$?

See if you can fill in the details - good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is such a group, then one of $a,b,c,d$ is the identity. Since $a,b,c,d$ are pairwise distinct, then the only possibility is that $d$ is the identity. In this case, $b$ and $c$ are inverses to each other. Now consider the inverse of $a$, say $a^{-1}$, then $a^{-1}\neq d$, since $a$ is not the identity. Also $a^{-1}\neq b$ and $a^{-1}\neq c$ otherwise $a=c$ or $a=b$. Last but not the least $a^{-1}=a$ is also impossible, otherwise we have $c=a^2=a^{-2}=b$. Thus we see that $a$ has no inverse element, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Good, but for a complete solution you also need to explain why $a^{-1}\ne a$.

Comment: @David That's a good point. If $a^{-1}=a$, then $a^{-2}=a^2$. since $a^{-2}=b, a^2=c$, we have $b=c$. Thus this cannot happen

Comment: Alternatively, $c=a^2=\hbox{identity}=d$, contradiction.

Comment: @David Exactly.