# fill in table - non-isomorphic groups - permutation.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am a student in computer science - first year. I study linear linear algebra 2 - course of linear algebra 1. - In some institutions academic studies teach the courses together / teach in another way.

I solved the question - but the way it is rather strange - without permutations.

"Consider the groups ({e, a, b, c}, ·) – that is, the groups of 4 elements. There are precisely
two such non-isomorphic groups (that is, essentially different). Here are the partially
filled multiplication tables for them:

1)
$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}*&e&a&b&c\\ \hline e&e&a&b&c\\a&a&e&\\b&b&&\\c&c\end{array}$$
2)
$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}*&e&a&b&c\\ \hline e&e&a&b&c\\a&a&b&\\b&b&&\\c&c\end{array}$$

Fill in the contents, so that the two will be non-isomorphic groups.
"

i fill the table and got :

1)
$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}*&e&a&b&c\\ \hline e&e&a&b&c\\a&a&e&c&b\\b&b&c&a&e\\c&c&b&e&a\end{array}$$

I have rejected the possibilities that I believe do not exist - for example:
bb = a - other option impossible.
bb cannot be e - lagrange's theorem, or c/b - because i can get 2 same element in the same row/column.

2)
$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}*&e&a&b&c\\ \hline e&e&a&b&c\\a&a&b&c&e\\b&b&c&e&a\\c&c&e&a&b\end{array}$$

fill like a sudoko.

I did not solve algebraic way - I think - is there a different way to solve these questions?

Comment: Note that your solution is not correct. You obtained isomorphic groups: Both are cyclic, the first one is generated by $b$ and the second one is generated by $a$. Your conclusion that $bb\neq e$ is not right.

Comment: Well done for showing that you've tried :)

Comment: I tried to find knowledge in the textbooks
how i tell that e have to in in b*b=e?
How do I reject my previous claim - that e cannot be equal to b*b?

Comment: You mean that: a to b - its like b to a? --SMM?

Comment: @Haham By Lagrange's theorem an element in a $4$-element group can have orders $1$, $2$ and $4$. If it has an element of order $4$, then the group is cyclic. It is clear from both tables that $e$ is the neutral. In the second table it is said $aa=b$, so $a$ is not of order $1$ or $2$, so it has to be of order $4$, and you filled the table perfectly. By the same reasoning, if in the first table you put $bb\neq e$ or $cc\neq e$, then you get an element of order $4$, and consequently the cyclic group. So the remaining option is to start filling the first table by $bb=cc=e$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The other, partially filled, is

$$ \begin{array}{c|lcr}*&e&a&b&c\\ \hline e&e&a&b&c\\a& a & e & & \\b&b& &e& \\c&c& & &e\end{array}.$$

The sudoku-like nature is because the tables are what are known as Latin squares.

Another way to show that there is only two is to use the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, although that is overkill.

Yet another way is to [assume such a group is not (isomorphic to) one of them, only to prove that it's (isomorphic to) the other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3158546/104041), since $A\lor B\equiv (\lnot A)\to B$ for any statements $A, B$.